# Passing data from UIView to UIViewController using protocol

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols

I'm trying to pass data from UIView contains UITableView to UIViewController but unfortunately, it doesn't work.

**Model:**

```
struct Recipes: Codable {
    let recipes: [Recipe]
}

struct Recipe: Codable {
    let title: String?
    let image: String?
    let pricePerServing: Double?
    let readyInMinutes, servings: Int?
}
```

The data should be passed from this `view`

**HomeView:**

```
protocol RecipesDetailsSelectActionDelegate: class {
    func recipeDetails(recipeTitle: String)
}

class HomeView: UIView {

    var recipes: Recipes?
    var recipesDetails = [Recipe]()
    let indicator = ActivityIndicator()

    weak var homeViewDidSelectActionDelegate: HomeViewDidSelectActionDelegate?
    weak var recipeDetailsViewSelectActionDelegate: RecipesDetailsSelectActionDelegate?

    override init( frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        layoutUI()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    lazy var foodTableView: UITableView = {
        let foodTableView = UITableView()
        foodTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        foodTableView.backgroundColor = .customVeryLightGray()
        foodTableView.delegate = self
        foodTableView.dataSource = self
        foodTableView.register(HomeTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "HomeTableViewCell")
        foodTableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        foodTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
        foodTableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        foodTableView.separatorStyle = .none
        return foodTableView
    }()
}

extension HomeView: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return recipesDetails.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell
            let url = URL(string: recipesDetails[indexPath.row].image ?? "Error")
            cell.foodImage.kf.setImage(with: url)
            cell.foodTitle.text = recipesDetails[indexPath.row].title

            if let readyInMin = recipesDetails[indexPath.row].readyInMinutes {
                cell.cookingTimeInfoLabel.text = "\(readyInMin) Minutes"
            }

            if let pricePerServing = recipesDetails[indexPath.row].pricePerServing {
                cell.priceInfoLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f", pricePerServing / 100)
            }

            if let serving = recipesDetails[indexPath.row].servings {
                cell.servesInfoLabel.text = "\(serving)"
            }

            return cell

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        recipeDetailsViewSelectActionDelegate?.recipeDetails(recipeTitle: recipesDetails[indexPath.row].title ?? "Error")
    }
}
```

**HomeViewController:**

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var mainView: HomeView = {
        let view = HomeView(frame: self.view.frame)
        view.recipeDetailsViewSelectActionDelegate = self
        return view
    }()

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        view = mainView
    }
}

extension HomeViewController: RecipesDetailsSelectActionDelegate {
    func recipeDetails(recipeTitle: String) {
        let vc = RecipesDetailsViewController()
        vc.mainView.recipeTitle = recipeTitle
        self.show(vc, sender: nil)
    }
}
```

The data should be passed to this `view`

**RecipesDetailsView:**

```
class RecipesDetailsView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        layoutUI()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    var recipeTitle: String?

    lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
        let tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
        tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.backgroundColor = .white
        tableView.register(IngredientsTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "IngredientsTableViewCell")
        return tableView
    }()

extension RecipesDetailsView: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "IngredientsTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! IngredientsTableViewCell
            cell.recipeTitleLabel.text = recipeTitle
            return cell
    }

}
```

**RecipesDetailsViewController:**

```
class RecipesDetailsViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var mainView: RecipesDetailsView = {
        let view = RecipesDetailsView(frame: self.view.frame)
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        return view
    }()

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        view = mainView
    }

}
```

Comment: What is *"not working"*? When you select a table row in `HomeView`, you are calling `recipeDetailsViewSelectActionDelegate?.recipeDetails(recipeTitle: recipesDetails[indexPath.row].title ?? "Error")` ... do you get an Error? Is `recipeDetailsViewSelectActionDelegate` nil? Is it calling the delegate function but nothing is happening there? Or wrong data is showing up? Or an error happens there?

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain this when I push to `RecipesDetailsViewController` but it doesn't pass the data to `RecipesDetailsView`

Comment: *"it doesn't pass the data"* -- which line of code is supposed to be passing the data?

Comment: In `HomeViewController` extension

Comment: Well, that's not a "line of code" but... So. what is not working? Does `recipeTitle` have the correct value in `HomeViewController extension`? Is it being set properly in `mainView`? You appear to be using it for just one row of a table... Is it valid in `cellForRowAt`? This is a very, very basic debugging task.

Comment: I'm trying to use `recipeTitle` in `RecipesDetailsView` to get a `String` and pass this data to `recipeTitleLabel` but it returns nil

Comment: You need to set breakpoints and inspect variables in your code.